# How to load just routs that I call using Vue.js and Vue-router

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I am developing an application SPA with Vue.js and I realized that when I call imports to load the routes using Vue-router it is loading everything.

My current code:

```
import Home from './components/Home/Home.vue';
import Product from './components/Product/Index.vue';
import Participant from './components/Participant/Index.vue';

export const routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        component: Home, 
        name: 'home',
        comments: {
            default: Home
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/product', component: Product
    },
    {
        path: '/participant', component: Participant
    },
    {   path: '*', redirect: '/' }
];
```

I was wondering if is there anything to load just part of the screen in order to be a truly SPA, I mean when it receives a click on the menu.

My menu code:

```
<router-link class="nav-item" tag="li" to="/"><a class="nav-link">Home</a></router-link>
<router-link class="nav-item" tag="li" to="/product"><a class="nav-link">Product</a></router-link>
<router-link class="nav-item" tag="li" to="/participant"><a class="nav-link">Participant</a></router-link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented something in a Vue.js project that I believe is what you looking for using in your application.

You need to change `imports` to `const` using `resolve` approach, however, Home should be as is because it is the default page

You can try the code below:

```
import Home from './components/Home/Home.vue';

const Product = resolve => {
    require.ensure(['./components/Product/Index.vue'], () => {
        resolve(require('./components/Product/Index.vue'));
    });
};

const Participant = resolve => {
    require.ensure(['./components/Participant/Index.vue'], () => {
        resolve(require('./components/Participant/Index.vue'));
    });
};
```

It allows to use lazy load concept, it will only load when called.